# Can I have multiple @BeforeMethod's that will run only for the groups they belong to?

Tags: java, automation, testng

```
@BeforeMethod (groups={"a"})
public void setup1() {
    //do something
}

@BeforeMethod (groups={"b"})
public void setup2() {
    //do something else
}

@Test (groups={"a"})
public void Test1() {
    //do something
}

@Test (groups={"b"})
public void Test2() {
    //do something
}

@Test (groups={"a"})
public void Test3() {
    //do something
}

@Test (groups={"b"})
public void Test4() {
    //do something
}
```

while the xml file would be something like:

```
<run>
    <include name="a"/>
    <include name="b"/>
</run>
```

Is it possible to have only setup1 run before Test1, Test3 while only setup2 runs before Test2, Test4?

Comment: That will work if you run only a or only b, not if you include both. If that's not what you want the easy way would probably be to split your tests in two classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to use is @BeforeGroups rather than @BeforeMethod.
BeforeMethod ensures that setup1 and setup2 both run before each method.
BeforeGroups would ensure that it would run only before specific group starts executing.

Comment: Is there a way to configure BeforeGroups method run before every Test that belongs to that group?

Comment: Well, nope, its configured to run just once per group.  If that is what you want, then you can continue using your example but in your xml file, make different <test> for each group.